# Custom design of UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm practicing my Swift coding and since I'm a designer I wanted to make custom design for my app. It is simple to do list app. It has 2 views. First is TableView with my to do items, and second view is about adding a new item.

My cell is rounded and has border color. How can I stylize a cell? I came across so many tuts but I haven't managed to find that answers my question.

I heard it can be done by stylizing prototype cell, but I don't really know how. I google everywhere and nothing I've found explains my question.

Here is my design:

[image: Home Screen of To Do App]

Can you guide me, please?

My code so far:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // Delete functionality
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            listItems.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // This function calculates how many rows our table has according to listItems array
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listItems.count
    }

    // Data in cells
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = listItems[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        // self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0);
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // Refreshing our table
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        listItems = savedItems.arrayForKey("UserInputs") as! [NSString]
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
    enter code here
```

I've set all options od background color to blue and for tint to be white and when I go into simulation, font of cell text is black. If somebody know how to fix this, let me now.

Comment: I would suggest giving it a go first and then posting questions, to point you in the right direction to start with, To Do & Add could be returned as a header & footer view respectively. To generate the cells as you want, you can customise TableCell's to achieve the appearance you want using Xcode's Interface Builder.

Comment: I managed to set border color and radius, but how about margin between cells? Is that possible?

Comment: Ideally your asking questions which can be answered with a quick search of Stack Overflow or Google. SO is usually a place for "I have issue X" or "I am seeing a weird behaviour Y", not so much a tutorial which seems to be what your after. If you get to a point where you are trying to achieve something and can't, show the code you are writing where you have tried that and people will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: I googled a lot and not a single valid answer so far. But I've updated my question with a code.

Comment: the border is not the cell border but a view that you put inside the cell. I would use a customCell. Do you have a storyboard in your app? I will answer the question later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Obtain that result your have to put a `containingView` inside a custom tableViewCell and give the radius and the white color to that `containingView` rather than the cell.

Start from the storyboard and add your `containingView` and `label` (I don't know what font you used):

[image]

I have decided to add a view on top of your `tableView` to get that result but I think you can use also `titleForHeaderInSection` and `willDisplayHeaderView` to get the same result.

Your `ViewContollerScene` should look like this:

[image]

But you also have to make sure that you assign the constraint to your `containingView` otherwise you won't get that result:

[image]

then make sure that you set the `identifier`
[image]

and the customClass that you created for your cell

[image]

Here the code:

**ToDoCustomTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ToDoCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var containingView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    containingView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    containingView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    containingView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    containingView.layer.masksToBounds = true

  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

}
```

and **ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

var listItems = ["item One" ,"item One","item One","item One","item One","item One" ]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
// Delete functionality
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        listItems.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// This function calculates how many rows our table has according to listItems array
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listItems.count
}

// Data in cells
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ToDoCustomTableViewCell
     cell.customLabel.text = listItems[indexPath.row]




    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

}
```

final result should be this. If you want to change the distance between your `containingViews` you just have to reduce the distance from the `contentView`. Just keep in mind that what your are seeing are the borders of your `containingViews` not your cell borders and that's the reason why you have to get rid of the cell separator.

[image]

Finally you can find the project on [gitHub](https://github.com/mat75/ToDo)

Answer (score 0):

1 Your Data source; always attempt to dequeue a cell first then allocate a new one if one doesn't get dequeued

```
// Data in cells
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell
  if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
  }
  cell.textLabel?.text = listItems[indexPath.row] as String
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
  cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
  cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15
  tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  // self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0);
  return cell
}
```

2 Remove viewDidAppear only if your doing logic that needs to be done after the view has appeared

3 Try setting the colour of the TableView in viewDidLoad and see if that changes anything.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    listItems = savedItems.arrayForKey("UserInputs") as! [NSString]
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Can you also update use with what your TableView is looking like? It will help if we can see what you are seeing and not just a concept.